# When, if at all, does initiative pass between players?

Tags: star-wars-armada

Just got *Star Wars: Armada* and we're still just playing the introductory scenario. The rules tell us that each round during phase 4 ("status phase") the player *with* the initiative token will flip it. In the expanded rules I see that after fleet construction we may have a new way of choosing who *starts* with the initiative token.

Does the initiative token ever pass from player to player? Or does it just stay in one player possession the whole game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not ever change hands. Initiative stays with whichever player had it at the start of the game. It's not really mentioned in the "starting to play" book, but the [Rules Reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/2c/4d/2c4de555-925d-4fde-8af6-02873437149b/swm01_rules_reference_guide_lowres.pdf) is pretty explicit:

> ### Initiative
>
> Initiative determines which player acts first during the
>   Ship Phase and Squadron Phase. It is assigned to a player
>   during the “Determine Initiative” step of setup. That
>   player is the first player and takes the initiative token. His
>   opponent is the second player.
>
> •   **The first player retains initiative for the entire game.**